# gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized is always false on page load

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I'm using gapi.analytics for Embed API and I'm verifying the authentication using the below code in `gapi.analytics.ready` function.

```
if (gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized()) {
  onAuthorize();
} else {
  gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', onAuthorize);
}
```

but `gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized()` is always returning false on page load.

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.on('needsAuthorization', function() {
   console.log('User is not Authorized!');
});
```

> When invoking the **gapi.analytics.auth.authorize** method, an initial check is made to see if the user is currently signed in. If the user is **not** signed in, this event is fired to indicate that further authorization is required.